# Screen Door Rollers Don't Turn

Tags: doors

I just removed my sliding screen patio door so that I can clean it and the tracks that the door wheels ride on. I noticed that the top door wheels still spin but both bottom wheels seem to be frozen ( and rusty). So that started me thinking can they both be bad or are they not supposed to spin in the first place, are they "sliding" wheels ? Any screen door experts here?

Comment: the top and bottom wheels are probably the same ... if they slid, then why would they be round?

Comment: The bottom wheels should spin if they do not a flat spot will be ground on the wheel and if a flat metal is sliding on a flat metal the rail will be damaged.  I have had several properties that I had flat wheels on sliding doors, some were easy replacements others took parts from other door frames and screws to get them sliding again.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but, I had to do a sanity check before bringing them to the hardware store for repair .

Answer (score 1):

Just spray some WD40 in there and work them a little bit. Dirt and moisture cause them to lock up over time.

Comment: WD40 on plastic is not a good idea. Petroleum based products will degrade many plastics. If lube is needed silicone grease at the bushing-journal interface will not degrade most plastics.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've used WD40 on mine and it works fine. Maybe I was lucky.

Comment: You can usually buy new wheels for this door at Ace Hardware, Home Depot, Lowes, Or any large hardware store.

Comment: @Jim Stewart - Just checked on your comment that WD40 is not a good idea on plastic. According to the WD40 website it is safe to use on rubber and plastic as is silicone grease which you recommended.. I've used it for years on plastics of various types - never a problem.

Comment: The wheels are so rusted and ugly they HAVE to be replaced. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: I had some bad experiences using light oil on plastic and assumed WD40 would be the same, but I evidently have made a false inference.